# Downloading binary files from github using Wget in python

Tags: python, github, wget

I am creating a program that grabs files from a GitHub repository, but `raw.githubusercontent.com` doesn’t work for binary files. If .ico files are not binary, then tell me how to download those.

I am using `wget.download()`, like this:

```
import wget
url = “ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repository/branch/file”
wget.download(url)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you to add a sample URL to your question to be able to reproduce the problem

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repository/branch/file

Comment: @CharonProgramer - that url gives a 404 error

Comment: Is this a public or a private repository?  Are these Git LFS files or regular Git files?

Comment: Public, I don’t know?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you add `?raw=true` to the end of a file, it should work.

For example: [the .ico for my homepage](https://github.com/hayesall/hayesall.github.io/blob/master/favicon.ico) cannot be viewed in the browser.

```
# Original Link
https://github.com/hayesall/hayesall.github.io/blob/master/favicon.ico

# (1) Appended with `?raw=true`
https://github.com/hayesall/hayesall.github.io/blob/master/favicon.ico?raw=true

# (2) Going through githubusercontent
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hayesall/hayesall.github.io/master/favicon.ico
```

Option (1) or (2) may be downloaded with `wget`:

```py
import wget
url = "https://github.com/hayesall/hayesall.github.io/blob/master/favicon.ico?raw=true"
wget.download(url)
100% [.......................] 1150 / 1150
```

Checking the downloaded file:

```
$ file favicon.ico
favicon.ico: MS Windows icon resource - 1 icon, 16x16, 32 bits/pixel
```

In Atom:

[image: Screenshot from Atom text editor, showing the code on top and the ico image data in the bottom window.]

Version information:

```
$ wget --version
GNU Wget 1.19.4 built on linux-gnu.
$ pip freeze | grep "wget"
wget==3.2
```

---

If this still isn't working, maybe it's a problem with `wget` (its most recent update was in 2015). Here's an alternative solution using [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```py
import shutil
import requests

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hayesall/hayesall.github.io/master/favicon.ico"
req = requests.get(url, stream=True)

assert req.status_code == 200

with open("favicon.ico", "wb") as _fh:
    req.raw.decode_content = True
    shutil.copyfileobj(req.raw, _fh)
```